# Understanding logarithmic law for geodesics

Tags: ergodic-theory, hyperbolic-geometry, hyperbolic-dynamics

I was reading this seminal paper

https://projecteuclid.org/journals/acta-mathematica/volume-149/issue-none/Disjoint-spheres-approximation-by-imaginary-quadratic-numbers-and-the-logarithm/10.1007/BF02392354.short

on logarithmic law of geodesics by Sullivan. I have trouble in understanding some of the details in the paper. It would be very helpful if someone could draw some light on these.

1. The section $6$ **Disjoint spheres and mixing of geodesic flow** he draws the picture in the universal cover. I am not getting how this statement follows ** The integral counts $e^{-dt}$ ( number of $\Gamma$ orbit balls approximately $t$ away from a fixed lift of $B$). So the orbit points is fixed width spherical shells is caught between two constant times $e^{dt}$.**I am not sure how this $e^{dt}$ terms are coming in integral count of number of orbit points**.
2. In the next page the term $e^{-d(x,\gamma x)}$ over one horosphere is commensurable to the largest term each being comparable to solid angle of the horosphere viewed from fixed lift of $B$. **I am not sure how this is coming i.e why the angle is $e^{-d(x,\gamma x)}$**
3. In *section 9* the main result i.e theorem 6 he has taken dist(v(t))=max{1, distance from a fixed point in $V$ to the point achieved after traveling time $t$ along the geodesic} . **I am just curious why we need to take maximum of 1 and distance from fixed pont, can't we work only with distance from fixed point to the point achieved after time $t$. I am not sure what is the need of $1$**.

In theorem $6$ he also used volume of the part $V$ where $dist\geq T$ bounded above and below by constant times $e^{-dT}$. Does this anyway follows from question 1 understanding?

I am sorry for the long post. But it would be very helpful if I can get a better understanding of this paper. Any help is very much appreciated.